# Is there a way to get the current user's name with having to Authorise the Google App Script

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, authorization, google-docs

I have created a Google Document template.  The template contains code that run from an OnOpen() trigger to auto-populate some basic information (Date, Classification, Title, version, author).  I ask for prompts to get the answers to these questions.  The problem is this: to get the Author's name, I know of no other way than to use this code:

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

Then I extract and format the name from the email address.

The problem is that the getEmail() function requires the user running the code to authorize the session.

This would not be a problem if users only had to do this once, but since this is a document template, any new document based on the template requires a re-authorisation of the code.

Is there a better way to get the Author's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Please see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser() for more information.

> Gets information about the current user. If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, `User.getEmail()` returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple `onOpen(e)` or `onEdit(e)` trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). **However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.**